# inheritance confusion. Adding a special class for making errors obvious on form validation

Tags: php, css, inheritance, forms, input

So I've got a form... The relevant CSS is (I think):

```
.libform input {
background-color:transparent;
color:#000;
border-left:0;
border-right:0;
border-top:0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
margin: 0 5px 1px 5px;
display:inline-block;
}
.libform input:focus {
border:0;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
color:#939;
background-color:#fed;
}
.error {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Form field:

```
<? if ($name=="") {$nameerror="error";}?>
<input name="name" type="text" class="<?php echo $nameerror;?>" value="<?echo $name;?>" id="name">
```

I'd like for when they've left the field blank the input button's underline to change from black to red. But it doesn't seem to inherit right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the class for the input supposed to be "error" the first time a user visits this page?

Comment: Nope. However when the user clicks submit it passes a hidden button to do validation, and if the form is valid passes the information, if it's not it cues the appropriate error(s). I simplified that a bit in the example and left out the validation bits to make it simpler. Good catch though. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely a specificty issue. try:

```
.libform input.error {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.libform .error`.

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/[CSS Specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/)